# Coordinates from twitter location data

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to pull the coordinates of a tweet. It looks like this after using json to load it.

```
tweet = json.loads(data)
print(tweet['coordinates'])
{'coordinates': [-86.771035, 39.514024], 'type': 'Point'}
```

I want to store the longitude and latitude into a database, how would I directly access the coordinates? I tried using tweet['coordinates'][0] and various variations but it doesn't seem to be working the way I want.

Comment: does tweet['coordinates'] return other dictionary?

Comment: So, try tweet['coordinates']['coordinates']. It is weird, but if it returns other dictionary like your question, it may work.

Comment: lat = tweet['coordinates']['cordinates'][0] and 
lng = tweet['coordinates']['cordinates'][1] should work

Answer (score 2):

You can get coordinates data in the following way:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='love',count = num_tweets).items():
    if (tweet.coordinates is not None): 
        lon = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][0]
        lat = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1]
```

It is strange, but I had to try many forms and ways to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
latitude, longitude = tweet["coordinates"]["coordinates"]
```

Because tweet["coordinates"] returns other dictionary that has a key also called "coordinates" with a list as its value.

Comment: not working for me, I get TypeError: 'Status' object has no attribute '__getitem__'